# Icon for Chrome missing after updating Windows-10 to November Update 1511

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, windows-update, icons, windows-10-v1511

After updating Windows-10 to November Update 1511, icon for Chrome is missing as in the screenshot, also Chrome and Firefox icons show gray background instead of theme color. Chrome icon shows when its resized to Medium but doesn't look nice.
In previous build 10240 it was showing it properly. Is this a bug in Windows update or chrome?

Comment: Your screenshot is not attached.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1001215/icons-for-chrome-and-firefox-missing-background-after-updating-windows-10-to-nov

Comment: Note that Edge loses the Start Menu tile icon after every Edge update as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same "issue". Managed to get it resolved for Chrome, digging for Firefox. In Chrome's folder (where chrome.exe is located) there is a visualelementsmanifest.xml file. Its purpose is to customize the appearance of the start screen tiles since Windows 8 days. It's created by default by Chrome's installer. For some reason, 10240 was ignoring it, now 10586 is loading it and it specifies a grey color - #323232. Delete the file. It may take some time for the tile to update, unpin and repin it, etc. Actually, best option is to change the icon of the shortcut to something else, than revert to the default one.

As for Firefox - not sure - no such file for it, so I do not know yet what is causing the customized greyish color.

Comment: See also http://krusted.com/guides/large-google-chrome-icon-fix/. Unpinning and repinning didn't work for me, but moving the shortcut to desktop and back worked.

Answer (score 2):

R.Click the shortcut, go to properties, click on the "Change Icon" button.(*) It will complain that "windows can't find the file ...". Enter "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" and your icon should be back. You can also try "%ProgramFiles(x86)% instead of %ProgramFiles%.
If it's still not back, manually browse to where chrome.exe is in the dialog box to change the icon.

(*) If it's a pin, you have to r.click the pin, the context menu is that of the pin. On the context menu of the pin, r.click the "google chrome" entity. That is the actual shortcut.

Comment: The shortcut isn't losing the location of the Chrome app, updates are somehow messing up the Start Menu tiles cached icon image.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Communication**
Here I found the shortcut to chrome which was pinned to the start menu.
Right click on the Chrome shortcut -> properties -> shortcut
Click on change icon button and choose any icon and click ok.

Now check your start menu.

Comment: This is a work around, but not really a "fix".