# Icons for Chrome and Firefox missing background after updating Windows-10 to November Update 1511

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-10, icons

After updating Windows-10 to November Update 1511, icon (more background of the icon) for **Chrome** and **Firefox** is missing as in the screenshot, also Chrome and Firefox icons show gray background instead of theme color.

Chrome icon shows when its resized to Medium but it's too big. In previous build `10240` it was showing it properly.

Is this a bug in Windows update or chrome, has anyone else noticed this? I have tried going back to the previous build (`10240`) and again reinstalling `1511` update but the 2 icons are still not fixed.

[image]